# How To Update Data Between Win Forms c#

Tags: c#

I Have to pass text value from txtform1.Text on Form1 to txtform2 on Form2.

I know How to pass value.I used following code.

Code In Form1 to open Form2 By Button Click

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//send message to contact chat
    {
        string value = txtform1.Text;
        Form2 f = new Form2(value);
        f.Show();
    }
```

code in Form2 to get the value

```
public Form2(string value)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         txtform2.Text = value;
    }
```

But this way the value can not be updated .

what i want is to update txtform2.text whatever i type in txtform1.text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form2 will need to have a public property

```
public string TxtForm2 
{
 set { txtform2.Text = value; }
}
```

you can add a get as well.  Then you can use

```
Form2.TxtForm2 = 'Some new value';
```